# Wait for all Tasks on the ThreadPool to finish

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-4.5

This might have a very simple answer, already posted here somewhere, but there is also a lot of old misleading information about threads.

My question is this: How do I prevent my Console from terminating before the background work is complete? Since the `Task` is created far down in the business layers of my program, I do not have access to it when the Console terminates (not like in this simple example). Is there some way of awaiting all Tasks that have been created within the context of my application?

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       DoBackgroundWork();
       System.Console.WriteLine("Doing something else during background work");

       // Wait for all created Tasks to complete before terminating
       ???
    }

    private static void DoBackgroundWork()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Starting background work");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Background work finished!");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you feel if you needed to add a helper class, and add all tasks to that?

Comment: Did you try **ManualResetEvent**?

Answer (score 3):

Return the task so that you can wait on it.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = DoBackgroundWork();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Doing something else during background work");

    // Wait for all created Tasks to complete before terminating
    task.Wait();
}

private static Task DoBackgroundWork()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Starting background work");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Background work finished!");
    });

    return task;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's the problem. Like I said in my question. The Task is actually created far down in my business layer, when the console stops, I don't have access to it. I can't return it all the way. Or maybe that's the only way to solve it. By using awaitable methods, but I was hoping to avoid that huge refactor it will take

Comment: I see, let me have a think :)